# Problema con custoadapter android

Tags: android, listview, edittext, customadapter

Tengo un `customadapter` en cual cargo detalles de cliente.

El detalle que tengo es que tengo un `edittex` en cada `item` que me muestro informacion y puede que un cliente tenga 10 detalles o notas de venta para aplicarle un pago el detalle es que cuando recorro mi `scrolll` hacia abajo los datos ingresado en la parte de arriba me los borra

```
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_detalle, parent, false);
            ((EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).addTextChangedListener(new TB_Abono_Watcher(convertView));


            ((EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setTag(O_CXCPDetalle);
            if (O_CXCPDetalle.TotalAplicado != 0) {
                ((EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setText(String.valueOf(O_CXCPDetalle.TotalAplicado));


            } else {
                ((EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setText("");
            }



            viewHolder.txfecha = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtFecha);
            viewHolder.txfolio = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtFolio);
            viewHolder.txtotal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.total);
            viewHolder.txttotal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txttotal);
            viewHolder.vencido = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtvencido);
            viewHolder.parcialidad = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.parcialidad);
            viewHolder.pagoforma = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pagoforma);
            viewHolder.ultimocobroob = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.UltimoCobroObservacion);
            viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            viewHolder.checkBox.setTag(new Integer(position));




            result = convertView;

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            result = convertView;
           // viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        }


        DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00");

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

        viewHolder.checkBox.setFocusable(false);
        viewHolder.txfecha.setText(dateFormat.format(O_CXCPDetalle.getFecha()));
        viewHolder.txfolio.setText(O_CXCPDetalle.getFolio());
        viewHolder.txtotal.setText(numberFormat.format(O_CXCPDetalle.getTotal()));
        viewHolder.txttotal.setText(numberFormat.format(O_CXCPDetalle.getSaldo()));
        viewHolder.vencido.setText(numberFormat.format(O_CXCPDetalle.getSaldoVencido()));
        viewHolder.parcialidad.setText((numberFormat.format(O_CXCPDetalle.getParcialidadTotal()) + " - " + O_CXCPDetalle.getParcialidad()));
        viewHolder.pagoforma.setText(O_CXCPDetalle.getPagoCondicionDescripcion());
        viewHolder.ultimocobroob.setText(O_CXCPDetalle.getUltimoCobroObservacion());
        viewHolder.checkBox.setEnabled(true);


     /*   viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked ){
                    System.out.println(position+"--- :)");
                    O_CXCPDetalle.setstatuscheck(true);

                }else{
                    O_CXCPDetalle.setstatuscheck( false);
            }
            }
        });*/

  /*          viewHolder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                    O_CXCPDetalle.statuscheck = true;

                } else {
                   O_CXCPDetalle.statuscheck = false;
                }
            }
        });*/


        double Abono = 0.00;
        Abono = O_CXCPDetalle.getTotal() - O_CXCPDetalle.getSaldo();
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pagado)).setText(numberFormat.format(Abono));

        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

y utilizo el `techwacher` para hacer la operación de suma

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {
        final CXCPDetalle o_CXCP_Detalle = (CXCPDetalle)((EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).getTag();

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("ONC_Settings", 0);
        if (settings.getInt("ONControlConexion", 0) == 0) {
            if (o_CXCP_Detalle.getViewChanged()==false) {

                o_CXCP_Detalle.TotalAplicado = ONC_SYS.NullToZeroDouble(s.toString());

                Double Total = 0.00;
                for (int i = 0; i < O_Resultado.DetalleArray.size(); i++) {
                    if (((CXCPDetalle) O_Resultado.DetalleArray.get(i)).TotalAplicado > 0) {
                        Total += ((CXCPDetalle) O_Resultado.DetalleArray.get(i)).TotalAplicado;
                        ((CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox)).setChecked(true);

                    }
                }
                DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00");
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.Total)).setText(numberFormat.format(Total));


             ((CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox)).setEnabled(true);
               ((CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("ONC_Settings", 0);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putString("ONControlCheck", String.valueOf(isChecked));
                        editor.commit();

                        o_CXCP_Detalle.setStatusCheck(String.valueOf(isChecked));


                        if (o_CXCP_Detalle.getStatusCheck() == "true")
                        {

                            ((Button)findViewById(R.id.pago)).setEnabled(true);
                            ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setEnabled(true);


                        }else
                        {
                            DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00");
                            ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setText("");
                            ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setEnabled(false);
                            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.Total)).setText(numberFormat.format(0.00));
                        }
                    }
                });




               if (o_CXCP_Detalle.getStatusCheck() == "true")
                {
                    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.pago)).setEnabled(true);
                    ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setEnabled(true);

                }else
                {
                    ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setEnabled(false);
                }

                //Validacion que no te deje hacer un abono Mayo al saldo vencido
                 if (o_CXCP_Detalle.getSaldo() < o_CXCP_Detalle.TotalAplicado) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No puedes Aplicar un Abono Mayor al SaldoVencido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setText("");

                }
            }
```

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
    private Detalle_Cliente dataSet;
    Context mContext;
    boolean[] checkBoxState;

    // View lookup cache
    public class ViewHolder {

        public TextView txfecha = null;
        public TextView txfolio = null;
        public TextView txtotal = null;
        public TextView txttotal = null;
        public TextView vencido = null;
        public TextView parcialidad = null;
        public TextView pagoforma = null;
        public TextView ultimocobroob = null;
        public CheckBox checkBox = null;
        public EditText cantidad;


    }

    public CustomAdapter(Detalle_Cliente data, ArrayList context) {
        super(data, R.layout.row_detalle, context);
        this.dataSet = data;

    }

    private int lastPosition = -1;



    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        final CXCPDetalle O_CXCPDetalle = getItem(position);
       // final ListViewItem item = getItem(position);
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        final ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag

        final View result;

        if (convertView == null) {

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_detalle, parent, false);
            ((EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).addTextChangedListener(new TB_Abono_Watcher(convertView));


            ((EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setTag(O_CXCPDetalle);
            if (O_CXCPDetalle.TotalAplicado != 0) {
                ((EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setText(String.valueOf(O_CXCPDetalle.TotalAplicado));


            } else {
                ((EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono)).setText("");
            }



            viewHolder.txfecha = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtFecha);
            viewHolder.txfolio = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtFolio);
            viewHolder.txtotal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.total);
            viewHolder.txttotal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txttotal);
            viewHolder.vencido = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtvencido);
            viewHolder.parcialidad = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.parcialidad);
            viewHolder.pagoforma = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pagoforma);
            viewHolder.ultimocobroob = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.UltimoCobroObservacion);
            viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            viewHolder.checkBox.setTag(new Integer(position));




            result = convertView;

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            result = convertView;
           // viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        }


        DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00");

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

        viewHolder.checkBox.setFocusable(false);
        viewHolder.txfecha.setText(dateFormat.format(O_CXCPDetalle.getFecha()));
        viewHolder.txfolio.setText(O_CXCPDetalle.getFolio());
        viewHolder.txtotal.setText(numberFormat.format(O_CXCPDetalle.getTotal()));
        viewHolder.txttotal.setText(numberFormat.format(O_CXCPDetalle.getSaldo()));
        viewHolder.vencido.setText(numberFormat.format(O_CXCPDetalle.getSaldoVencido()));
        viewHolder.parcialidad.setText((numberFormat.format(O_CXCPDetalle.getParcialidadTotal()) + " - " + O_CXCPDetalle.getParcialidad()));
        viewHolder.pagoforma.setText(O_CXCPDetalle.getPagoCondicionDescripcion());
        viewHolder.ultimocobroob.setText(O_CXCPDetalle.getUltimoCobroObservacion());
        viewHolder.checkBox.setEnabled(true);


     /*   viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked ){
                    System.out.println(position+"--- :)");
                    O_CXCPDetalle.setstatuscheck(true);

                }else{
                    O_CXCPDetalle.setstatuscheck( false);
            }
            }
        });*/
```

/*          viewHolder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

```
                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                    O_CXCPDetalle.statuscheck = true;

                } else {
                   O_CXCPDetalle.statuscheck = false;
                }
            }
        });*/


        double Abono = 0.00;
        Abono = O_CXCPDetalle.getTotal() - O_CXCPDetalle.getSaldo();
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pagado)).setText(numberFormat.format(Abono));

        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar toda la clase del Adapter por favor.

Comment: ya agregue todo el codigo del adpater

Answer (score 1):

Esto es el resultado del reciclaje que utiliza el ListView esto se utiliza para un mejor rendimiento de la memoria.

Lo que puedes hacer es en el textWatcher guardar el dato que escribio el usuario en el edittext de los item de la lista en el item O_CXCPDetalle

Y en el getView de tu adapter recuperar nuevamente el dato, asi cuando la listView reclicle los item cuando vuelva a crear el item seguira teniendo el mismo valor ya que lo estas guardando.

En esta pregunta podras leer mas información de como funcionan las ListView: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works